# Cursor getPosition is always 0

Tags: android, android-layout, android-cursoradapter

I have a cursor for which getCount returns 50. Needing to display the content in a ListView, I am using a cursor adapter as below. For some strange reason, the list always contains one element. Upon logging, I am seeing that `cursor.getPosition()` is always 0. Why is that? I have been using CursorAdapters for a while now and I have never had this problem before. So I am baffled and can’t see what I am doing wrong.

```
Cursor cursor = getContext().getContentResolver().query(uri, PROJECTION,null,null,null);
    MyLog.d(TAG,"cursor count is %s",cursor.getCount());
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    CursorAdapter cursorAdapter = new CursorAdapter(getContext(),cursor,true){
        @Override
        public View newView(Context context,Cursor cursor,ViewGroup parent){
            MyLog.d(TAG,"newView cursor count %s position %s",cursor.getCount(),cursor.getPosition());
            return LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.my_row,parent,false);
        }

        @Override
        public void bindView(View view,Context context,Cursor cursor){
            MyLog.d(TAG,"bindView at index %s",cursor.getPosition());
            TextView name = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.name);
            TextView address = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.address);
            String naTxt = cursor.getString(COL_NAME);
            String addTxt = cursor.getString(COL_ADDR)
                    +" "
                    +cursor.getString(COL_STR);
            name.setText(naTxt);
            address.setText(addTxt);
        }
    };

    root.setAdapter(cursorAdapter);
```

Comment: Have tried without `cursor.moveToFirst();`? It has been a while since I used CursorAdapter, but I think you should just pass the cursor as it is, instead of moving the position.

Comment: Yes. That's how I started. I added moveToFirst to see if that would fix the issue.

Comment: Override getView() instead. One of the parameters is the position.

Comment: CursorAdapter requires that I override newView. Also, I am literally sitting here and staring at an older project that I built the same way. And that project has been publish and worked. So I am not sure what is going on. The only difference is gradle version and that the new project that is not working has minSdkVersion 21

Comment: I am using `android.support.v4.widget.CursorAdapter` if that matters

Answer (score 1):

I find the problem, which indeed is a new thing in the latest android since I haven't seen it before. For the row layout, I had `android:layout_height="match_parent"`. I was supposed to be using `android:layout_height="wrap_content"`. Beats me.

Answer (score 0):

Please try to remove

> cursor.moveToFirst();

And use

```
CursorAdapter cursorAdapter = new CursorAdapter(getContext(),cursor,0)
```

Instead of `CursorAdapter cursorAdapter = new CursorAdapter(getContext(),cursor,true)`

And you should use `android.widget.CursorAdapter`